# Access IIFE variables from developer tools

Tags: javascript, developer-tools, iife

Let me preface this by saying that I am aware it is not programmatically access inner variables of an IIFE from outside, unless they have been made accessible to the global scope.

For example:

```
(function() {
    var a = "Hello"; // a isn't accessible from the outer scope
)();

console.log(a); // a is undefined
```

But:

```
(function() {
    var a = "Hello";
    global.a = a;
)();

console.log(a); // Displays "Hello"
```

In some cases, it is possible that the IIFE will keep executing for several seconds, or during the entire duration of the page browsing, typically in the case of games written in JavaScript, where the IIFE will contain the game loop.

Therefore, all the variables and functions declared within the IIFE must exist in the browser memory, but, due to the encapsulation, they can't be displayed from the developer console.

My question is: is there any way I could still display or manipulate those, without previously modifying the code, while it is running? Since those variables are present in memory and being used? Perhaps through debugging of some sort?

My question is mostly for Firefox and Chrome (Firebug and developer tools), but if there is a general way to do it that would work too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Put a breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints?hl=en) inside the IIFE, on a line of code that will be run in the future.

When the breakpoint is hit, the console will be in that scope.

```js
(function() {
  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

  var a = 1;
  
  function myFunction (ev) {
    debugger; // You could also add this breakpoint using the Dev Tools UI
    console.log("A is ", a);
  }
})();
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: Will this allow me to edit the variable (and have the rest of the code use the edited value)?

Comment: Yes. (And since comments have a minimum length, it took me all of 10 seconds to check that with the demo in the answer).

Comment: Thank you, simple and working. (I tried checking with that demo but didn't manage to locate the code)